# Can a slightly bent rim cause an outer CV boot leak?

Tags: steering-wheel, wheels, cv-joint, ball-joint

After a severe pothole, I bent very slightly my front right rim right before a road trip. As the effect wasn't noticeable, I went on my road trip.

I noticed the clamp on my CV boot had gone loose on the side which points the wheels itself.

I am just wondering is it, in theory, possible that the bent rim is causing too much vibration and therefore loosening the clamp or was that just a result of a bad repair job (a couple of weeks ago I had the boot replaced after I ran over a shoe which tore it open)?

P.S. I'll fix the bent rim this week most likely.

Comment: The bent rim was not likely to be the cause of the cv clamp being loose. But you need to get this sorted properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The shop took responsibility and fixed it for me at no cost on the same day I reported it. They're my go-to guys and I accept a mistake sometimes happen and they dealt with it properly. It has been fixed for around a week with no issues but I had been second doubting the bent rim as a  possible cause.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

A bent rim, even one severe enough to cause vibration, will not loosen a CV clamp that is already subject to constant vibration.